# I can not use MAX function in android sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I built max function in dbhandler class as below:

```
@Override
public int getIDmax() {
    int MAX =0;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    try{
        String QUERY = "SELECT MAX(KEY_MESSAGE_ID) AS KEY_MESSAGE_ID FROM "+TABLE_NAME ;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(QUERY,null);
        MAX =cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_MESSAGE_ID);
        db.close();
        return MAX;

    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("error",e+"");
    }
   return 0;
}
```

Now I want to get maximum number in KEY_MESSAGE_ID column
my code in main activity is as below:

```
int b = handler.getIDmax();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+b,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

But when I run application it return 0;
what is the problem???

Comment: So ?? Is it working or not ?

Answer (score 2):

You made a mistake to recover the value,
you are getting the index of the column, not the value.

To get the value, call

> cursor.getInt(indexColumn)

You can use the getIndexColumn or hardcode this index (safe with this query)

PS : I am not sure of the position in the cursor at the beginning, so I would set the position to be sure with

> cursor.moveToFirst()

Edit : Here is how I would do it (not tested)

```
@Override
public int getIDmax() {
    int MAX = -1;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    try{
        String QUERY = "SELECT MAX(_message_id)  FROM "+TABLE_NAME ;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(QUERY,null);
        cursor.moveToFirst(); //Set the position to the beginning, current position is -1. You can check if there is something in the cursor since this return a boolean
        MAX = cursor.getInt(0);

        db.close();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("error",e+"");
    }
    return MAX;
}
```

Comment: PS : You should return -1 if there is a mistake, if not, you will not be able to detect an error.

Comment: i changed getIDmax() as below:

Comment: I have edited the answer, I can't test this but this should work. You need to know that the cursor you received point to the -1 row, you need to set the position first or use moveToNext to increment this position index.